# error: C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'QKeyEvent':

Tags: c++, qt

No puedo incluir esta librería a mi aplicación. Intente incluirla del siguiente modo:

```
#include <QEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
```

Sin embargo me muestra el siguiente error:

> user\filtro\filtrodeeventospersonalizado.cpp:4: error: C1083: No se
>   puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'QKeyEvent': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QKeyEvent` se encuentra en la librería `GUI` de Qt. Si no incorporas dicha librería al proyecto no podrás hacer uso de dicha clase.

Para incluir la librería basta con añadir lo siguiente al proyecto:

```
QT += gui
```

También puede pasar que tengas algo tal que:

```
QT -= gui
```

Con lo que en teoría bastaría con eliminar dicha línea.

Un saludo.